# Node.js EPIPE при попытке записи в порожденный процесс

Tags: node.js

Использую `child_process.exec` для создания порожденных процессов. Далее в порожденный процесс через стандартный поток ввода записываю данные. Вот пример того, как я это делаю:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var cmd = exec('./a-command-that-does-not-exist', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
     if (err) {
        console.log('callback');
        console.dir(err);
    }
});

cmd.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('event');
    console.dir(err);
});

cmd.stdin.write('test data');
cmd.stdin.end();
```

Суть проблемы в следующем. Если при вызове `exec` я передаю в качестве первого аргумента имя (путь) несуществующего скрипта, то вместо ошибки о том, что скрипт не может быть выполнен я получаю:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:718:19)
```

Пробовал в node.js 0.10.20 и 0.12.6 (Linux и Windows соответственно).

Собственно вопрос: в каких еще случаях выбрасывается `EPIPE` и можно ли как-то понять, что скрипт не может быть выполнен до вызова `cmd.stdin.write`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка с кодом `EPIPE` обычно возникает при попытке записи в еще не открытый или уже закрытый `writable`-поток. В данном случае, поток не может быть открыт, потому что дочерний процесс не может быть создан.

Порядок возникновения ошибок определяется асинхронной природой JavaScript, но тут есть одна тонкость. Все экземпляры `EventEmitter` в node.js по-особенному работают с событием `error`. Если для этого события не назначено ни одного обработчика, то node.js завершиться с сообщением:

> Unhandled 'error' event

Именно это и происходит с примером в вопросе. Если же все-таки определить обработчик для события `error` на `stdin`, тогда функция обратного вызова, переданная в `exec`, вызовется с ошибкой. Вот как это можно использовать:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var cmd = exec('./missed-command', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(err);
});

cmd.stdin.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('stdin error: ' + error.code);
});

cmd.stdin.write('test');
cmd.stdin.end();
```

Код из примера выше, выполненный в Linux, выведет:

```
stdin error: EPIPE
{ [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: 1: ./missed-command: not found
] killed: false, code: 127, signal: null }
```

Стоит отметить, что код ошибки, переданной в функцию обратного вызова `exec` **зависит от операционной системы** (и, возможно, от используемой оболочки командной строки). В Linux этот код равен `127`, а в Windows -- `1`. Если порождаемый процесс активно использует ненулевые коды возврата, то это может стать проблемой. В Windows отличить отсутствие порождаемой команды от случая, когда эта команда завершается с кодом `1` можно только по сообщению об ошибке. В таких случаях, проще всего использовать `spawn` вместо `exec` (однако, этот путь имеет и свои минусы). Вот как это можно сделать:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var cmd = spawn('./missed-command');

cmd.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('cmd error: ' + error.code);
});

cmd.stdin.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('stdin error: ' + error.code);
});

cmd.stdin.write('test');
cmd.stdin.end();
```

Этот код выведет вот такие сообщения в консоль:

```
stdin error: EPIPE
cmd error: ENOENT
```

Можно заметить, что порядок ошибок остался таким же, но вторая ошибка порожденного процесса имеет осмысленный код (`ENOENT`).